# CSS effect fill only the text not the box

Tags: css, text, elementor

I am trying to underline the Elementor heading with css class and an effect of heading filled with color from bottom upon hovering. The following code fills the whole box. How can I limit it to fill only the heading without custom adjusting padding for each box? Thank you!

Just as described above.

```css
.da {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -8px 0 -1px #028DB8;
  transition: box-shadow .45s ease-in-out;
  color: black;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.da:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -40px 0 -1px #AED476;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <title></title>
  </head>
<body>
<div class="da">
    <h2>Simple Text</h2>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the animation on `h2` element.
Remove `line-height` and add `display:inline-block` so the `widht` of the `h2` element is exactly long as the text

```css
h2 {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -8px 0 -1px #028DB8;
  transition: box-shadow .45s ease-in-out;
  color: black;
  display:inline-block;
  /*line-height: 40px;*/
}

h2:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -40px 0 -1px #AED476;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <title></title>
  </head>
<body>
<div class="da">
    <h2>Simple Text</h2>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @sfili_81. Happy new year to you and loved ones.